# Using the same variable across multiple files in C++

Tags: c++, variables

In the process of changing some code, I have spilt some functions into multiple files. I have the files `controls.cpp` and `display.cpp` and I would like to be able to have access to the same set of variables in both files. I don't mind where they are initialized or declared, as long as the functions in both files can use them.

This was not an issue when the functions were in the same file, but now it seems almost impossible after an hour of googling and trying various things.

Comment: This is of course very poor practice - you should redesign your code rather than do this.

Comment: this is the purpose why `extern` keyword is present in c

Comment: This of course begs the question why you have global variables at all.

Comment: Boost::test uses global variables to keep track of test cases. Thrift uses global variables for constants. However, in Sam152's case it does seem like a bad idea.

Comment: @benjamin The C language has the extern keyword to make NAMES visible between translation units, not (with a very few exceptions) VARIABLES.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Define the variable in one file like:

```
type var_name;
```

And declare it global in the other file like:

```
extern type var_name;
```

Comment: Better yet: put the `extern type var_name` into a header and include this in all the other files instead of putting the declaration into them manually.

Answer (score 7):

use those variables as `extern` 
i.e.

```
extern int i;
```

in another file declare same as normal global variable...

```
int i;//global
```

Answer (score 4):

Create two new files:

1. Something like `Globals.h` and declare all variables like: `extern type name;`

   - btw remember include guards.
2. Something like `Globals.cpp` and declare variables like: `type name;`

Then add `#include "Globals.h"` at the top of:

- `Globals.cpp`
- `controls.cpp`
- `display.cpp`

You may then want some functions to initialise them.

Comment: Can they be initialised in Globals.cpp?

Comment: @Sam152: Yes, I suggest creating a function that lives in `Globals.cpp` and declaring it in `Globals.h`

Comment: @Sam152 See my answer below for a trick that allows you to declare and initialize the variables all in the .h file.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially all you have to do is declare the variable once in one code file, and declare it in the others as extern (making sure NOT to initialize it when you are declaring it extern, or some compilers will ignore the extern keyword, giving you compiler errors.)

The simplest way to do this is to use a macro in a header file, like such:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __MAIN__
    #define __EXTERN(type, name, value)     type name = value
#else
    #define __EXTERN(type, name, value)     extern type name;
#endif
```

and then declare your variables in that same header file, like such:

```
__EXTERN(volatile int,  MyVolatileInteger,  0);
```

from any ONE file in the project, include the header file, like such:

```
#define __MAIN__
#include "Globals.h"
```

from all the rest, just simply include it normally, like such:

```
#include "Globals.h"
```

Presto, you're done.  Variables only declared once, and initialized in-line.  This is very maintainable, and saves you the trouble of having to declare everything twice.

Answer (score -1):

All of the declarations you want visible in multiple compilation units (.cpp files), should go into a header file that you include in all places that need to use the variable, type, class, etc.

This is vastly better than extern, which essentially hides your intention to share the declaration.

Comment: You can't do that. It'll need to be both extern *and* in the header file or else you'll get redeclaration errors.

Comment: Redeclaration and "extern" are totally orthogonal issues. I should have mentioned that every header you write needs to have "include guards" surrounding its content:

#ifndef UNIQUE_NAME_OF_HEADER_FILE_HPP
#define UNIQUE_NAME_OF_HEADER_FILE_HPP

... declarations ...

#endif

Or if your compiler supports it #pragma once